# How to split the oauth logic and create the Google Calendar service

Tags: cakephp, oauth, calendar

I am using php client for Google Calendar API
https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client and CakePHP.

Basically, I just want to manage the events in the calendar. 
And I could do it following the example here https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/user-example.php. It worked fine (so, I have no problems with client id, client secret etc).

The only problem is that in the example it's all written in one file - the oauth logic and service specific logic (like retrieving events from calendar). So the redirect uri in google console points to the same file.

The pseudo-code for this is:

```
//here we create the client which is used for authentication
$client = new Google_Client();

//some of the oauth logic
$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
//other oauth logic

$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
$events = $service->events->list();
//...
```

So, as you see, to create a service we need a client (which contains the access token and all the authentication data needed for service).

I want to split it, so that I have the callback where I could retrieve the client and then use it for creating the service. I could have also specify that callback in google console as a redirect uri.

I have a feeling that there should be some standard way which unfortunately I am not aware of. I broke my head thinking about how to do this, so any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
As it often happens, right after posting a question here I managed to do something.
After we get an access token, we need to save it into DB.

Next time, when we want to do something with the api, we create the google client again and just set the access token with the value from the DB. So that we don't need to go through the oauth logic again.

Something like this:

```
$accessToken = $db->getOne('SELECT token FROM users WHERE id=:id');
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($clientId);
$client->setClientSecret($clientSecret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirectUri);
$client->setAccessType($accessType);
$client->setScopes($scope);

$client->setAccessToken(json_encode($accessToken));
```

Well, it looks obvious. But still I'd like to get an answer from experts to this question:
 is recreating the google client object the right approach?

Thanks.

Comment: Why should that be the _wrong_ approach? What kind of problems are you afraid of? ps, are you aware of the limited [**token lifetime**](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#expiration)? pps. how is this related to CakePHP?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Hmm, token lifetime is an issue.. As for CakePHP, I use it and I thought it might matter for the answer. I also tried to use Opauth and its CakePHP plugin. Though, I am not sure if I can use it for getting access to calendar events (I get a warning when I specify a calendar scope). So, can I use Opauth for my purposes?

Comment: CakePHP, yes, it may matter for the answer, but just knowing that you are using CakePHP isn't enough, you would have to explain where exactly your code is located and when it is being triggered. Generally you should be able to use any OAuth 2 compatible library, if you're having specific problems with Opauth, then that might be something for a new question.

Comment: Ok, then I will post a new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**CakePHP 3.x in  Google Calendar API**

- Follow this steps:
- Create google calendar api

  https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=calendar&pli=1
  Composer to install:

  "google/apiclient": "^2.0"

  Required google calendar api integration
- https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=calendar&pli=1
  https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php
- Create project and create secret key and client id Project in set
  name and redirect URL
- NOTE:- redirect URL must be .com and .org

  domain If you develop in local machine then create follow type of
  virtual host             example.com and example.org Virtual host create then

  Follow this step:

Set configuration file in app_globle.php

```
'Google' => [
      'ClientID' => '7441260037.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        'ClientSecret' => 'kashdjahdkjshdkjhjAs',
        'RedirectUrl' => 'http://' . env("HTTP_HOST") . '/oauth2calendars',
        'ClientCredentials' => WWW_ROOT . 'files'. DS.'google.txt',
        'Scopes' => implode(' ', [Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR, Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE, Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_FILE, Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_APPDATA, Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA]),
    ]
```

**Route**

```
 $routes->connect('/events/add', ['controller' => 'Events', 'action' => 'add', ['_name' => 'add-event']);
    $routes->connect('/events/edit/:id', ['controller' => 'Events', 'action' => 'edit', ['id' => '\d+', 'pass' => ['id'], '_name' => 'edit-event']);
    $routes->connect('/events/delete/:id', ['controller' => 'Events', 'action' => 'delete', ['id' => '\d+', 'pass' => ['id'], '_name' => 'delete-event']);
```

**Controller**

```
use Google_Client;
use Google_Service_Calendar;
use Google_Service_Calendar_Event;
use Google_Service_Drive;
use Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile;
```

**Authorize the google Oauth thriugh**
/**
     * get Google calendar client
     */

```
private function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAccessType("offline");
    $client->setClientId(Configure::read('Google.ClientID'));
    $client->setClientSecret(Configure::read('Google.ClientSecret'));
    $client->setRedirectUri(Configure::read('Google.RedirectUrl'));
    $client->setScopes(Configure::read('Google.Scopes'));
    $credentialsPath = Configure::read('Google.Credentials');
    if (file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($credentialsPath), true);
    } else {
        // Request authorization from the user.
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        return $this->redirect($authUrl);
    }
    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    // Refresh the token if it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
        $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        file_put_contents($credentialsPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}
```

/**
     *** Create Google Calendar event**
     */

```
public function createCredentials()
{
   $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAccessType("offline");
    $client->setClientId(Configure::read('Google.ClientID'));
    $client->setClientSecret(Configure::read('Google.ClientSecret'));
    $client->setRedirectUri(Configure::read('Google.RedirectUrl'));
    $client->setScopes(Configure::read('Google.Scopes'));

           if (isset($this->request->query['code'])) {
        $client->authenticate($this->request->query['code']);
        $token = json_encode($client->getAccessToken());
        $credentialsPath =WWW_ROOT . 'files'. DS.'google.txt';
        if (!file_exists(dirname($credentialsPath))) {
            mkdir(dirname($credentialsPath), 0700, true);
        }
        $file = new File($credentialsPath, true);
        $file->write($token);
        $client->setAccessToken($token);
        return $this->redirect(‘/add-event’);
    }
}
```

**Add event functionality**

```
Public function add()
{
$client = $this->getClient();
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                $dateStart = new \DateTime($this->request->data['start_date_time'], new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
                $dateStart->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
                $startDate = $dateStart->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $dateEnd = new \DateTime($this->request->data['end_date_time'], new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
                $dateEnd->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
                $endDate = $dateEnd->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $guests = $this->request->data['guests'];
                $eventGuest = [];
                $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
                foreach ($guests as $key => $value) {
                    $eventGuest[$key]['email'] = $value;
                }
                $eventData = [
                    'summary' => $this->request->data['name'],
                    'location' => $this->request->data['location'],
                    'description' => $this->request->data['description'],
                    'start' => [
                        'dateTime' => date("c", strtotime($startDate)),
                    ],
                    'end' => [
                        'dateTime' => date("c", strtotime($endDate)),
                    ],
                    'attendees' => $eventGuest,
                    'reminders' => [
                        'useDefault' => true,
                    ],
                    'visibility' => 'private',
                    'privateCopy' => true,
                ];
                $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event($eventData);
                $sendNotifications = ['sendNotifications' => true];
                $calendarId = 'primary';
                $eventDataResponse = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event, $sendNotifications);
          }

}
```